# MySQL Check if any row has a date in the future

Tags: mysql, group-by

(The following schema has been minified to reduce the problem)

I'm having two tables `Products`:

```
| ID         | ProductName       | AvailableDate (date)
|------------------------------------------------
| 1          | Foo               | 2011-01-01
| 2          | Bar               | 2017-01-01
| 3          | FooBar            | 2011-01-01
```

and `Mappings`:

```
| ID         | ProductID       | SomeOtherID
|------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 1               | 1
| 2          | 2               | 1
| 3          | 3               | 2
```

A Mapping can point to `n`Products:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(`Products`.ProductName SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM 
  Mappings
JOIN 
  Products ON Mappings.ProductID = Products.ID
GROUP BY 
  Mappings.SomeOtherID
```

I now want to extend the query to check if *any of the rows in `Products` have an AvailableDate that is larger than the current Date* to spot the combined Products, that have at least one "early-access" Product.

I tried the following

```
SELECT 
      GROUP_CONCAT(`Products`.ProductName SEPARATOR ', '),
      IF(COUNT(DATEDIFF(`Products`.AvailableDate, CURDATE)) > 0, 1, 0) As IsEarlyAccess
    FROM 
      Mappings
    JOIN 
      Products ON Mappings.ProductID = Products.ID
    GROUP BY 
      Mappings.SomeOtherID
```

but i always receive `IsEarlyAccess = 1`. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to use an IF on a MAX rather than COUNTing an IF:-

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Products.ProductName SEPARATOR ', '), IF(MAX(Products.AvailableDate) > CURDATE(), 1, 0) As IsEarlyAccess 
FROM Mappings 
JOIN Products ON Mappings.ProductID = Products.ID 
GROUP BY Mappings.SomeOtherID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - so simple, yet so effective! Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You problem lays here:

```
      IF(COUNT(DATEDIFF(`Products`.AvailableDate, CURDATE)) > 0, 1, 0) As IsEarlyAccess
```

Your count is this :

```
COUNT(DATEDIFF(`Products`.AvailableDate, CURDATE))
```

Which will count 1 for any record,regardless of the result, since it will be executed as `count(4)` `count(-2)` ETC..

Change it to  this:

```
IF(SUM(DATEDIFF(`Products`.AvailableDate, CURDATE) > 0) > 0, 1 , 0)
```

Which will count 1 for each record that its available date is larger then today.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can actually get away with:

```
MAX(Products.AvailableDate) > CURDATE() As IsEarlyAccess
```

or

```
MAX(Products.AvailableDate > CURDATE()) As IsEarlyAccess
```

MySQL takes boolean true as 1 and false as 0.